# Your Apple ID has been disabled [Environment: Sandbox]

Tags: iphone, ipad, testing, app-store, in-app-purchase

i am testing my application in-app purchases with iTunes test account.

I run the game and i log-in to sand box test account.
when try to buy something in the app a message box prompt me with confirm your in-app purchase information.

Then I click “Buy” it ask me for Apple ID Password for my sand box account. When I give the password it prompt me with following message ...

Your Apple ID has been disabled.
[Environment: Sandbox]

I tested with several test accounts same result. Can anyone provide some help on this?

Answer (score 4):

If you use sandbox IAP test accounts to login to real iTunes Store or in Settings app, your sandbox account gets disabled.

I can't find the exact documentation URL right now, but I'm sure I have read it.

Here is a warning message from documentation:

Important: Do not sign in with your test account in the Settings application.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to new iOS Paid App agreements that haven't been agreed to yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you log out of your real account in the App Store app before using a test user account.